# Appengine mercurial error

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy mercurial for google app engine and keep getting this error. Please see if anyone has a solution.

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named pwd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ajatus-graphics/2.339364808142331297/hgapp.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ajatus-graphics/2.339364808142331297/hgapp.py", line 23, in main
    from dashboard import dashboard
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ajatus-graphics/2.339364808142331297/dashboard.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mercurial import templater, templatefilters, util
  File "/base/python_dist/lib/python2.5/py_zipimport.py", line 242, in load_module
    exec code in mod.__dict__
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ajatus-graphics/2.339364808142331297/hg.zip/mercurial/templater.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/base/python_dist/lib/python2.5/py_zipimport.py", line 242, in load_module
    exec code in mod.__dict__
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ajatus-graphics/2.339364808142331297/hg.zip/mercurial/util.py", line 543, in <module>
  File "/base/python_dist/lib/python2.5/py_zipimport.py", line 242, in load_module
    exec code in mod.__dict__
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ajatus-graphics/2.339364808142331297/hg.zip/mercurial/posix.py", line 10, in <module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the unix password database in the App Engine sandbox, so the `pwd` module isn't installed.

In general, many random python modules will require extensive hacking to get them to run on App Engine.

Answer (score 3):

maybe one of these projects will be of use?

1. http://bitbucket.org/durin42/mercurial-appengine/overview
2. http://appgallery.appspot.com/about_app?app_id=agphcHBnYWxsZXJ5chQLEgxBcHBsaWNhdGlvbnMYne8BDA (see also https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2008-December/022692.html )

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is remove import **pwd**. Because when you run on GAE, you don't need this module.